# How to change working directory using Net::SSH2?

Tags: perl, ssh, net-ssh

```
use Net::SSH2;
my $ssh2 = Net::SSH2->new();
$ssh2->connect($hostname);
$ssh2->auth_password($user,$pass);
$chan = $ssh2->channel();
$chan->exec("cd dir1");
$chan->exec("command file1.txt");
```

The above doesn't work and `command` cannot find `dir1/file1.txt`.  How do you change the working directory using [`Net::SSH2`](http://search.cpan.org/~salva/Net-SSH2-0.62/lib/Net/SSH2.pm)?

Comment: #$chan->exec('ls -la'); [referred from here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=569657)

Comment: @ssr1012 That would list the directory. I don't want to do that.

Comment: `$chan->exec("./command");`

Comment: @JimGarrison Why does that work?

Comment: Because on Linux the current directory is not included in the path automatically.  you must either add it yourself or remember to invoke local programs (ones in cd) using `./`

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~salva/Net-SSH2-0.62/lib/Net/SSH2/Channel.pm), each invocation of `$chan->exec()` runs in its own process on the remote. The `cd dir1` in the first `exec` affects only that execution. The next `exec` is a completely separate process.

The simplest way to solve the problem would be to pass the full path in the command, i.e.

```
$chan->exec("command dir1/file1.txt");
```

You could also try setting the PATH variable using `$chan->setenv()` but that probably will be prohibited by the remote side.

Note also (from the `process` section):

> ... it is also possible to launch a remote shell (using shell) and simulate the user interaction printing commands to its stdin stream and reading data back from its stdout and stderr. But this approach should be avoided if possible; talking to a shell is difficult and, in general, unreliable.